# Nessus Report Total 0?

Tags: network-scanners

This may seem like a slightly esoteric question but, I am wondering if it possible to achieve a result summary in Nessus where the Total is 0 for a windows server? Things that have no risk factors like, "Host Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) Resolution", "Additional DNS Hostnames", "OS Identification", etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nessus runs a set of plugins that you define and you can choose to disable.  If you need to show a scan with zero findings, you should disable the checks that you don't care about and mitigate or resolve the findings you do care about.

The simplest way to do this would be to disable ALL of the checks and run Nessus.  Some people (myself included) would consider that cheating.  That's why it's important to consider the thoroughness of a test along with the result.

Comment: First thank you for your comment. Totally agree I wouldn't want to disable ALL checks it wouldn't really make any sense. Generally I like to run the defaults depending on what I am doing. Maybe another way to phrase the question is how many people disable "OS Identification"?? Or how many mediums, lows, and infos do you think is acceptable (knowing that this is a relative term).

Comment: Keep in mind that the defaults come from the Nessus makers best guess about what most people want or need.  They can't really understand how you're using it or the risk level you're comfortable with.  The easiest way to do this is not rely on the Nessus classifications.  Take the Nessus report and review it, creating your own list of relevant findings.  Then address those.